# How to send the current working directory as an argument in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line-interface, batch-file

I want to send a path as an argument to an executable.
what I want to do something like this:

```
pushd some\folder
set x=cd
popd
MyExe.exe %x%
```

the problem is that the x variable is now equal to the string "cd" but what I want is to get the output of cd into x.
How do I do that?

Comment: I wasn't quite understanding what you wanted - why can't you just use the %1%, %2% etc variables if you are passing parameters into the script? Is there some reason why you need to validate the path?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Windows maintains the current directory in the environment variable `%CD%`.

```
echo %CD%  
c:\users\user
pushd c:\temp
echo %CD%
c:\temp
set X=%CD%
popd 
MyExe.exe %X%
```

will pass c:\temp to MyExe.exe

Comment: This isn't an environment variable; it's merely a "pseudo-variable". Whenever you use those, keep in mind to delete an actual variable of that name before as their magic doesn't work when a variable with that name exists.

Answer (score 6):

The `%CD%` pseudo-environment variable contains the current working directory and is available within CMD\Batch files.

In your case a batchfile that just contains `MyExe.exe %CD%` will do what you want.